# Why do we denote $S^1$ for the the unit circle and $S^2$ for unit sphere?

Tags: general-topology, notation, intuition

Maybe a quite easy question. Why is $S^1$ the unit circle and $S^2$ is the unit sphere?

Also why is $S^1\times S^1$ a torus? It does not seem that they have anything in common, do they?

Comment: What kind of answer are you seeking? The superscript denotes the dimension of the space for $S^n$. $S^1 \times S^1 $ is homeomorphic to whatever space you like to think of as the torus. Perhaps you can specify what type of information you'd like.

Comment: $S^n$ is $n$-dimensional, and refers to those elements of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ with norm $1$. The $n$ simply denotes its dimension.

Comment: $S^n$ is defined in a uniform manner for all $n$ (the easiest way may be as the set of points $p\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ satisfying $|p|=1$); you can convince yourself that the two examples you've given fit that pattern.

Comment: As for your question, "why is $S^1\times S^1$ a torus?" ... have you ever tried to parametrize a torus before? Did you, for instance, google the word "torus," click the link to the Wikipedia page, and look at the pictures?

Comment: Also, you can see a torus as a circle 'swept around' a circle; this is (roughly) how the torus is thought of as $S_1\times S_1$.

Comment: I guess your question probably isn't really "Why is this notation used?" because the universal answer to that is "Because one or more people thought it was a useful shorthand." Are you implicitly asking something like "Why is the unit circle $S^1$ and not $S^2$?

Comment: @blue: thanks for the advice. I was searching it in wikipedia of my country and there is not such an animation. Well, i asked, because for me it would also make sense to denote the unit circle, by $S^2$, since it is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: It's denoted by $S^1$, not $S^2$, because it's one-dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not going to be the best answer, but $S^n$ is a $n$ dimensional manifold in general. I.e, we can write this out in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as

$$ x_0^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 =1 $$

I'm sure you've seen how these give a circle and a sphere in the case of $n=1,2$.

For understanding the Cartesian product $S^1 \times S^1$, you can think of it as gluing a circle to every point of another circle. This gives a torus.

Answer (score 3):

$S$ means *sphere* and 1 resp. 2 gives the number of free parameters. From [Sphere:Generalization to other dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Generalization_to_other_dimensions).

> Spheres can be generalized to spaces of any dimension. For any natural number $n$, an "[n-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)," often written as $S^n$, is the set of points in $(n + 1)$-dimensional Euclidean space that are at a fixed distance $r$ from a central point of that space, where $r$ is, as before, a positive real number.

When you put the center of a unit circle at every point of another unit circle you get a torus.

Comment: I can't seem to find the link anymore, but this confusion about the dimension has come up more than once here, I think. It's usually beneficial to note that the dimension at work is a topological dimension, rather than a "geometric dimension." Students look at a circle as a $2$-D shape geometrically, and then don't get that topologically it can be described with a single parameter.

Comment: @rschwieb This is a very good point!